# c# - elsa workflow - child workflow - how to get workflowInstanceId of parent workflow

Tags: c#, child-process, custom-activity, elsa-workflows

I have an elsa workflow `parent` which is calling some `child` workflows.
Every child workflow has some custom activities  (based on `SendHttpRequest` elsa activity).
These custom activities need to call an external api and provide the `workflowInstanceId` of `parent` workflow.

I tried to pass the `workflowInstanceId` of `parent` as `ContextId` of child workflow – not working since is overridden inside of child workflow custom activity (which makes sense of course).

How could I get (server-side) the `workflowInstanceId` of `parent` workflow from a piece of code which is running on a child workflow
(let’s say from `OnExecuteAsync(ActivityExecutionContext context)` of child workflow custom activity)?

Comment: I also tried to set `Custom Attributes` from `Run Child Workflow` with `workflowInstacenId` of parent workflow but don't know how to get these values on server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Elsa 2 (2.6 at the time of writing) does not have a real notion of parent-child workflows (i.e. workflows invoked by other workflows do not have any reference to their parent), you can use the `RunWorkflow` activity to provide arbitrary **input** to the child workflow. Including its own workflow instance ID.

For example, use the following JS expression on the `RunWorkflow` activity to send the workflow instance to the child workflow:

```js
({ parentWorkflowInstanceId: workflowInstanceId })
```

Then, from your child workflow, your first activity should be the one to capture this value, e.g. using a `SetVariable` activity:

```js
input.parentWorkflowInstanceId
```

Now that you have the parent workflow instance ID stored in a workflow variable, you can access it from anywhere in your child workflow.

Here is an example of a parent workflow you can import via the designer:

```json
{
  "$id": "1",
  "definitionId": "f3da997090fe4752b4f7abf799f372a8",
  "versionId": "8d6c6e2b441a4d22952a7b19ebf9ceca",
  "name": "Parent",
  "version": 2,
  "variables": {
    "$id": "2",
    "data": {}
  },
  "customAttributes": {
    "$id": "3",
    "data": {}
  },
  "isSingleton": false,
  "persistenceBehavior": "WorkflowBurst",
  "deleteCompletedInstances": false,
  "isPublished": true,
  "isLatest": true,
  "activities": [
    {
      "$id": "4",
      "activityId": "2952daee-646e-431f-b02b-006557507755",
      "type": "RunWorkflow",
      "displayName": "Run Workflow",
      "persistWorkflow": false,
      "loadWorkflowContext": false,
      "saveWorkflowContext": false,
      "properties": [
        {
          "$id": "5",
          "name": "WorkflowDefinitionId",
          "syntax": "Liquid",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "6",
            "Liquid": "{{ \"Child\" | workflow_definition_id: \"name\" }}"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "7",
          "name": "Input",
          "syntax": "JavaScript",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "8",
            "JavaScript": "({ parentWorkflowInstanceId: workflowInstanceId})"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "9",
          "name": "PossibleOutcomes",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "10"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "11",
          "name": "Mode",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "12"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "13",
          "name": "TenantId",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "14"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "15",
          "name": "CorrelationId",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "16"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "17",
          "name": "ContextId",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "18"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "19",
          "name": "CustomAttributes",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "20"
          }
        }
      ],
      "propertyStorageProviders": {}
    },
    {
      "$id": "21",
      "activityId": "2a6d90ee-5e7a-4d68-8629-386abdaf70ad",
      "type": "HttpEndpoint",
      "displayName": "HTTP Endpoint",
      "persistWorkflow": false,
      "loadWorkflowContext": false,
      "saveWorkflowContext": false,
      "properties": [
        {
          "$id": "22",
          "name": "Path",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "23",
            "Literal": "/parent"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "24",
          "name": "Methods",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "25",
            "Json": "[\"GET\"]"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "26",
          "name": "ReadContent",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "27"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "28",
          "name": "TargetType",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "29"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "30",
          "name": "Schema",
          "syntax": "Literal",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "31",
            "Literal": ""
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "32",
          "name": "Authorize",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "33"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "34",
          "name": "Policy",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "35"
          }
        }
      ],
      "propertyStorageProviders": {}
    }
  ],
  "connections": [
    {
      "$id": "36",
      "sourceActivityId": "2a6d90ee-5e7a-4d68-8629-386abdaf70ad",
      "targetActivityId": "2952daee-646e-431f-b02b-006557507755",
      "outcome": "Done"
    }
  ],
  "id": "8d6c6e2b441a4d22952a7b19ebf9ceca"
}
```

And here is the Child you can import:

```json
{
  "$id": "1",
  "definitionId": "81efcdb2f9aa473a84931814f5ee1c65",
  "versionId": "cc21182603564d68876efd9079382c27",
  "name": "Child",
  "version": 1,
  "variables": {
    "$id": "2",
    "data": {}
  },
  "customAttributes": {
    "$id": "3",
    "data": {}
  },
  "isSingleton": false,
  "persistenceBehavior": "WorkflowBurst",
  "deleteCompletedInstances": false,
  "isPublished": true,
  "isLatest": true,
  "activities": [
    {
      "$id": "4",
      "activityId": "83c6931f-f481-47c0-add8-3b1ea7d864a2",
      "type": "SetVariable",
      "displayName": "Set ParentWorkflowInstanceId Variable",
      "persistWorkflow": false,
      "loadWorkflowContext": false,
      "saveWorkflowContext": false,
      "properties": [
        {
          "$id": "5",
          "name": "VariableName",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "6",
            "Literal": "ParentWorkflowInstanceId"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "7",
          "name": "Value",
          "syntax": "JavaScript",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "8",
            "JavaScript": "input.parentWorkflowInstanceId"
          }
        }
      ],
      "propertyStorageProviders": {}
    },
    {
      "$id": "9",
      "activityId": "80e7eb8f-3fca-42a7-be3d-16827bd6ba38",
      "type": "WriteHttpResponse",
      "displayName": "HTTP Response",
      "persistWorkflow": false,
      "loadWorkflowContext": false,
      "saveWorkflowContext": false,
      "properties": [
        {
          "$id": "10",
          "name": "Content",
          "syntax": "Liquid",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "11",
            "Liquid": "Parent ID: {{ Variables.ParentWorkflowInstanceId }}"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "12",
          "name": "ContentType",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "13"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "14",
          "name": "StatusCode",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "15"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "16",
          "name": "CharSet",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "17"
          }
        },
        {
          "$id": "18",
          "name": "ResponseHeaders",
          "expressions": {
            "$id": "19"
          }
        }
      ],
      "propertyStorageProviders": {}
    }
  ],
  "connections": [
    {
      "$id": "20",
      "sourceActivityId": "83c6931f-f481-47c0-add8-3b1ea7d864a2",
      "targetActivityId": "80e7eb8f-3fca-42a7-be3d-16827bd6ba38",
      "outcome": "Done"
    }
  ],
  "id": "cc21182603564d68876efd9079382c27"
}
```

Once imported, make sure both workflows are published.
You can then invoke the parent workflow via its HTTP endpoint, e.g.: `https://localhost:11000/parent`

Which will result in a response similar to this:

```
Parent ID: 0178617bbeca47088e74330c0905237c
```

This response is generated by the Child workflow (which successfully received the parent workflow instance ID)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. In the meantime I found a similar solution. 
I passed the `parent` instance Id to `child` worflow via `ContextID` of `child` workflow.
Then, as you suggested, the very first step was to “intercept” the contextID and set the `parent` InstanceID as a workflow variable into the `child` wokflow.
I followed this aproach since the child workflows already require a dedicated input so I didn’t want to modify the structure of that input.

Comment: From my perspective a more convenient solution would have been to pass any custom value from `parent` to `child` workflow via `Advanced`->`Custom Attributes` of `parent` workflow. I tried to add some values on that field of `parent` worflow but I wasn’t able to get them on `child` worlflow side – don’t know how to access in `elsa designer` a custom attribute